# Ajax call get post intelligence

Tags: javascript, ajax, crud

I have seen a horrible and also interesting thing today. Please have a look at this ajax call to a web api post method.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'api/AccountAPI/GetByNickName',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ ConnectedUserNickName: key }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
              alert('successful');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

It occurs an error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)". This ajax call doesn't hit the server side "GetByNickName" method.

If I change the method name to "checkNickName" or anything then it works fine. It looks so interesting to me. Can anyone tell what's happening here.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'api/AccountAPI/CheckNickName',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ ConnectedUserNickName: key }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
              alert('successful');
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

When I noticed that error is occuring because of method name "GetByNickName", I thought there may be some intelligence in ajax post/get method name. So, what is the actual reason??

Comment: what is the back-end language?

Comment: backend asp.net web api. @SunilMishra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET the `Web API framework` by default maps incoming requests to the appropriate action based upon the `HTTP verb` of the request.

So if you specify `GetByNickName` this corresponds to HTTP Verb `GET`, where as `CheckNickName` doesn't corresponds to any HTTP Verb, hence it works in your case.

An example would be suppose you have an action in `AccountAPI`

```
public void Get(int id)
```

Your URI would look `api/AccountAPI/{id}`

For more details read the [routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) and [action selection](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection) documentation and check the [sample application](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)